# Xamarin Forms Style FontSize not working

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a simple Style for setting some Label properties. All the Setters seem to work fine except the FontSize which seems to be ignored.

```
<Style x:Key="UpgradeMainBlueHeader" TargetType="Label">
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35" />
     <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
     <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource colorBase}" />
</Style>
```

If I set FontSize directly on the Label it works fine, so I am puzzled on what is going on here?

(Am using VS Mac, iOS Emulator - iPhone X)

### Update

The only way I can currently get this to work is by using OnPlatform to create a Resource, and then use this resource in the Style.

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Font" 
                        Android="30" 
                        iOS="30" 
                        WinPhone="20" 
                        x:Key="TitleFontSize" />

<Style x:Key="UpgradeMainBlueHeader" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource TitleFontSize}" />
            </Style>
```

Any reason why this works, but the original code doesn't? Could this be a Xamarin version or simulator issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the xamarin docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/styles

According to the documentation this should work. Even we are using this attribute in our styles and it works as expected.

The values we are using :

```
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22.44" />
```

Check if in your xaml or in *.cs class you are overwriting this fontsize.

However in an old xamarin discussion (below link), check nprokopic's comment :

He said `<Setter Property="FontSize"` didn't work thus he used `<Setter Property="Font"` and this worked for him.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32814/style-fontsize-onplatform-in-xaml

Comment: Exactly what worked for me. The question is why? I cant see any reason why the standard FontSize=22.44 wouldn't work as it seems to be commonly used in all examples I am seeing?

Comment: I'm sorry got little confused by your comments. Did it work ??

Comment: Yes "Font" works, but "FontSize" doesn't work. Its strange because most of the Xamarin documentation and even throughout Xamarin University, they use "FontSize" and they are adamant it works on their side?!?

Comment: Check the Xamarin version you are using. It might be obsolete, you might need to update it.

Comment: Using the latest (2.4.0.282). There doesnt seem to be much clarity in the docs which is the correct way to do things in regards to font sizing from what I can see. Both ways are shown, but only the OnPlatform one works for me. Just curious as to why.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar since upgrading to Xcode 9.4.1. See my post on the Xamarin.Forms forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/128330/xcode-9-4-1-seems-to-break-styles-on-ios#latest

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

App.xaml

```
    <Color x:Key="colorBase">#00FF77</Color>
    <Style x:Key="UpgradeMainBlueHeader" TargetType="Label">
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35" />
         <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource colorBase}" />
    </Style>
```

View:

```
<Label Text="Hello World" Style="{StaticResource UpgradeMainBlueHeader}"/>
```

Comment: What version of XCode are you using? I've just upgraded from XCode 9.2 to XCode 9.4.1, and am seeing similar behaviour. With XCode 9.2, my Styles work fine. With XCode 9.4.1 Label BackgroundColor, for example, only works if I create a StaticResource (like you've done) with an OnPlatform.

Comment: Hey @JamesLavery Best to create a new Question, I doubt its related to fontSize, don't forget to include sample code.

Comment: I agree - I'll add a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue with the XAM140/Exercise 4/Completed project from Xamarin university Using Visual Studio for Mac 7.5.3--using a Style in the ResourceDictionary to modify the font for the Label elements had no effect on the label.

The fix for me was to open the Packages folders in the solution explorer, right click on the Xamarin.Forms package, and update it to the latest version (3.1.0.583944 at the time).  I updated Xamarin.Forms in all targets, then for good measure did a full clean and restarted Visual Studio before opening and running the project.

After the update, the problem was fixed, and the  began working as expected both in the design preview and running on device.

```
<Style x:Key="myLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"   />
</Style>
```

Now works for the label:

```
<Label x:Name="billLabel"  Text="Bill"  Style="{StaticResource myLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
```